# Start network connections last on boot

Tags: openbsd

Running `OpenBSD 6.7` as my perimeter device with a number of services installed to monitor the network.

The problem is `netstart` runs early in the boot process resulting in the interfaces being unprotected and unmonitored for some time.

Ideally I'd like for the interfaces to come up last. At least after the other network based services have already started.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but maybe you could achieve this with `pf`: block everything by default in `/etc/pf.conf` but add an `anchor` rule that you can use later in the boot process to "inject" a `pass` rule, e.g. in `rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

@zé-loff, thanks for the feedback! The following is what I did and testing proved successful. While this technique successfully blocks traffic until all services have started, everything in `netstart` will still run as normal. Meaning requests such as ARP and DHCP will be exchanged before the pf ruleset is loaded.

### /etc/pf.active.conf

Copy the current pf ruleset to this file. It should contain every allow/block rule necessary for the system to operate. Below is an example of the default ruleset.

```
#   $OpenBSD: pf.conf,v 1.55 2017/12/03 20:40:04 sthen Exp $
#
# See pf.conf(5) and /etc/examples/pf.conf

set skip on lo

block return    # block stateless traffic
pass        # establish keep-state

# By default, do not permit remote connections to X11
block return in on ! lo0 proto tcp to port 6000:6010

# Port build user does not need network
block return out log proto {tcp udp} user _pbuild
```

### /etc/pf.conf

Update with just a single line to block all traffic. This ruleset can be customized for your environment. For example block all traffic except pfsync or still allow traffic on the internal interface.

```
block drop quick
```

### /etc/rc.local

Create or update `/etc/rc.local` with the following as it is launched last in the boot process.

```
# Load actual pf rules.
if [[ $pf != NO ]]; then
    if [[ -f /etc/pf.active.conf ]]; then
        pfctl -f /etc/pf.active.conf
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You don't need to edit `rc`, which will complicate things when upgrading the system (see `man sysupgrade` and `man sysmerge`). You can do this the other way round: have the "boot only" rules on `/etc/pf.conf` and keep the "real" rules in, say, `/etc/pf.conf.post_boot` and load that file in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: @zé-loff, you're right that's a much better approach and have updated my post. Thanks!